# Is the string literal "browser" a recognized keywords when using Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("browser")?

Tags: asp.net, .net

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77a0146y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) illustrates how to use the `HttpCachePolicy.SetVaryByCustom` method. However, the example passes the string literal "browser" as the parameter to this method without explaining if the string literal is a recognized keyword in the ASP.NET runtime.

How does the implementation of this method know that we mean "user agent" when we pass the string literal "browser"? While *User Agent* and *Origin Server* are terms recognized by the HTTP RFC 2616, I don't see any mention of the word "browser" anywhere but in the said example.

What are the valid values that can be passed to this method?

Comment: Even this might not be constructive regarding your question, but why would something which is made for standardized html Output vary by browser?

Comment: `SetVaryByCustom` lets you choose your own key. That is the reason, It doesn't have to be recognized. Valid values can be any string that you find appropriate enough by which you want to cache and differ the response.

Comment: Thank you. So, I have to write my own code to *react* to the presence of absence of that key in the cache, right?